# SSO: Using outlook.com accounts to login to Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a webapp that is using SSO to login users. I am trying to intergrate the SSO with Microsoft Azure AD (Since the webapp is hosted on Azure AD). I have enabled Multi-tenancy, So users from other domains are able to login without any issue. But the users from outlook.com are unable to login to the application. If a user from outlook.com tries to login, they get the following error.

Sign In
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 59cfb21d-d91a-4fa9-b71a-b058d873fde1
Timestamp: 2017-02-01 03:06:26Z
AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Accounts' and cannot access the application 'xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it seems that we cannot merge the Org Accounts (like the accounts in Office 365/ AAD) with Microsoft Accounts (LiveId, hotmial...).

To achieve your requirement, you can try to configure the `easy auth` feature of Azure App Service. Configure both AAD and Microsoft account for Authentication / Authorization, as mentioned at [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).

Then you can perform a custom login page, for multiple providers. You can get a hint from post ["Easy Auth" / App Service authentication using multiple providers](https://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/easy-auth-app-service-authentication-using-multiple-providers)

Comment: Thanks Gary for the quick response. The link to the second URL is broken?

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Looking at the link, It seems like I have to create a button for <Login with Microsoft> and another one for <login with live.com>. But single button solution is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Gary for your help!

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT you can use both AAD accounts with Microsoft Accounts using the Azure AD v2.0 converged endpoint. aka.ms/aadv2

Comment: @DanielDobalian. Yes, you are correct. Here is the link that describes how it can be done.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview. Since I am using JS. I had to modify the v1.0.13 of adal.js to get the v2.0 request. But even though my request include scope=openid+profile+email. The profile + email  info is not present in the token. Is there a new version of ADAL.js that I can use?

Comment: For v2.0, you can use the most popular open source library, hello.js.  Expect a code sample on https://github.com/azure-samples soon.

Comment: Thanks @DanielDobalian